# In HTML form with email field, a browser message "View Saved Logins" covers up the "Please enter an email address" message

Tags: html, forms, validation, autocomplete

I have a simple HTML form, something like:

```html
<form action = "register.php" method = "post" autocomplete = "off"> 
    <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "Email" id = "email" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">    
</form>
```

By setting `type = "email"`, some helpful validation features are activated. For example if I enter an "email" that does not have the @ symbol and try to submit the form, a message "Please enter an email address" will appear. Unfortunately, in my browser (Firefox), this helpful message is covered up by a "View Saved Logins" message. Is there any way to prevent this, for example by changing the position of one of the messages?